# PostgreSQL, insert with select fails on conflict do update

Tags: sql, postgresql

I try to resolve to do an update when the pk fails on an insert in pg12. I think, it's easy, just an on conflict in the query... but no.
When I run the query, I got this error:

```
ERROR:  column excluded.fec does not exist
LINE 25: ...ON CONFLICT (address) DO UPDATE SET saldo.fecha = EXCLUDED.f...
                                                              ^
SQL state: 42703
Character: 1052
```

The table:

```
CREATE UNLOGGED TABLE wallet.saldo
(
    address character varying(42) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    fecha timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    saldo numeric(60,20) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT wallet_saldo_address_pk PRIMARY KEY (address)
)
```

The query:

```
INSERT INTO wallet.saldo(address, fecha, saldo)

select  '0xaa515035c04aab' as token_address,  max(block_timestamp)::date as fec, sum(importe) as imp 
from (

    SELECT 
        tt.block_timestamp, tt.value::numeric(60,20) / ('1' || left('0000000000000000000000000', t.decimals))::numeric * -1 as importe
    FROM raw.token_transfers tt inner join raw.tokens t on t.address = tt.token_address
    where to_address = '0xaa515035c04aab'
    and tt.block_timestamp between '20201009 00:00:00' and '20201009 23:59:59.99999'

    union

    SELECT 
        tt.block_timestamp, (tt.value::numeric(60,20) / ('1' || left('0000000000000000000000000', t.decimals))::numeric) as importe
    FROM raw.token_transfers tt inner join raw.tokens t on t.address = tt.token_address
    where from_address = '0xaa515035c04aab'
    and tt.block_timestamp between '20201009 00:00:00' and '20201009 23:59:59.99999'

) as det

ON CONFLICT (address) DO UPDATE SET saldo.fecha = EXCLUDED.fec,  saldo.saldo = EXCLUDED.imp

;
```

The select DET works fine, return the correct values,  the error is the same if try to replace EXCLUDED with DET (the alias)

Please, what I'm doing wrong???

Comment: error message is super clear : " column **fec** does not exist" , nor imp column

Comment: yes, thank you, you are right, I copy one version of the query and the result of the previos. I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EXCLUDED always refers to the column names of the *target*  table not the source. You also can't use the target table name on the left side of the assignment.

So you need

```
SET fecha = EXCLUDED.fecha,  
    saldo = EXCLUDED.saldo
```

Comment: Thank you so much! yes! I just removed the table name set.